# Is the automated testing still referred to as smoke testing?

Tags: testing, smoke-testing

If not, is [smoke testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_test#Smoke_testing_in_software_development) still used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's sort of a Venn Diagram.  Some Automated tests are Smoke tests, and some smoke tests are Automated (inasfar as they are ran by a computer program).  A Smoke test is a take off (if I recall correctly) on the term "Where there's smoke, there's usually fire."  It's a set of preliminary tests that the program must pass to be considered for 'real' (viz. fire) testing.

A smoke test can be manual insomuch as a tester has a list of steps he follows, but these aren't automated with a computer program.

Smoke testing is still used -- in places I've worked, it's usually automated.

Answer (score 3):

Automated testing can do smoke testing (shallow, wide), but it can also do other testing like [regression testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing), and [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). Basically automated testing can be any repeatable test.

Yes, smoke testing is still being used. I've generally seen two scenarios. The first is to determine whether the software is ready for more in depth testing. The second, and IMO more common, to skimp on fully testing functionality that should not have been affected by the changes to the new build.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think smoke tests are usually automated. The smoke test in my experience is really just a basic sanity test to make sure that subsequent tests can actually be run, and that nothing basic got broken like startup code or menu entries. This would usualy be done manually by a person. I suppose it could be automated, but usually it involves the addition of new features so the automated tests would have to be changed as well and you'd still have the same problem that you'd need a person to verify that the automated tests were modified to test the new feature properly. In contrast, automated tests (like unit tests) represent a regression test suite and are created to test well-established functionality that should not change much from release to release, although of course you would add unit tests to cover new functionality as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably more in companies from a hardware background where the smoke test was taken literally. Few people call them that anymore. It's usually just a small yet broad subset of a larger acceptance or system test suite. These tets are automated and are automatically run against code before it is submitted or on submission to source code control.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure we can compare Smoke and Automated testing. Smoke testing is a way to run a set of basic tests on a build, covering all the basic features but not going in depth on any. The purpose is to determine whether a build can be used for more detailed testing or not. It is also a set of steps that can be run quickly even on a developer build to determine if there are any issues due to some significant or core changes that are about to go in a build. We consider Smoke test to be one of our 'test plans' but one that is run on every build.

Automated testing is not specific to Smoke tests but can be applied there as well. It is done to 'automate' redundant or repetitive steps that a tester always does to save time. That is the primary purpose of automation. It is allowes a tester to spend more time to do other tests.

It can never be replacement of testing by a real brain nor everything can be automated. It is an activity that supplements the testing process in place, not replace it.

Since Smoke test is potentially run on every build, there is a good value in automating it. If a smoke test run manually takes 4 hours, and after automation it takes 1 hour, you have saved an effort of 3 man-hours * number of builds.

There are several tools in market for automation testing - AutoIT and SilkTest to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

In very simple words we can say that Smoke testing can be automated but it is not like automated testing is always smoke testing.

Yes, smoke testing is a popular way of testing any application/software.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of "smoke testing" is different than the wikipedia article. I understand smoke testing to be the developer opening the app and testing the basic functionality to verify that the app looks right & is doing the basics. So I always thought it was a manual process, not an automated one.

Comment: What Wikipedia describes is, I think, more like regression testing. I've never even heard of this testing before testing before.

Comment: Under my definition of smoke testing, it can't be automated.  Never heard of smoke testing being used in a framework context...

Answer (score 0):

Test automation suite contains various levels like smoke test, acceptance test, nightly build, so on. Its up to the tester to decide which test case needs to be run in each level. Each test case is numbered depending upon the levels at which they should be run. Say if there are 2 test cases automated, numbered with 1 and 2 respectively to indicate the levels, and you define test level as 2 in configuration file, its gonna run only the second test case and gives you the result. Smoke test generally has less number of test cases compared to acceptance test.

Smoke test can be automated but not all automated tests are smoke tests.